# Magento 2 how to get html from admin/sales/order/view

Tags: magento2, theme-overriding

I am trying to figure out that how can I get the html that would be rendered on below page:

> "www.mysite.com/admin/sales/order/view/order_id/12345/"

But I am not able to figure it out. I am trying to get it within my own custom module, apply some styling changes to it, and convert it into a PDF. I have all the other stuff figured out, I just need to get the raw html that would output to this page. I don't even know where to start with this.

Comment: You can do but some customization on your module.

Comment: did you found solutions for this? I tried to use file_get_contents to scrap html for print URL but it is not working because we need to login to view sales order view page

Answer (score 1):

`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` is the file you are looking for. Here you can find all the templates used on this page. You can just copy the html of these files to your own template files & apply changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it and need some code at your modules. I am trying to explain the steps that will be required for this requirement.

Magento generate the HTML output of a page using `multiple blocks and templates files and layout`,So if you want to change something this page, then you  have to work at `sales_order_view.xml`

1. As you want to create sales_order_view.xml at your module `app/code/{VendorName}/{Modulename}/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` and add a CSS file from this file.
2. And below code  that

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <head>
         <css src="Vendor_Module::css/order.css"/>
       </head>
    </page>`

them Add order.css file in web folder as below path:

`app/code/{VendorName}/{Modulename}/view/adminhtml/web/css/order.css`

You want to change html structure  of this page then you have to work on phtml  files on `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`

Comment: I believe this process will only change the styling on the original page. I still want that page to display as it currently is, but I also want to take a copy of the HTML that will render on that page, modify it a little, and export it out as a pdf. What I am looking to do is click a button on this page that will export that page as a pdf, not change the styling of the original page.